# ayuda Input select Dinamico con ajax y jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Soy nuevo en la programación, y necesito su apoyo por favor:

Por defecto si cargan los datos, pero necesito que el cliente tenga que seleccionar este input antes de guardar, debe mostrar  "Seleccionar", y así el cliente este obligado a selecionar el input(), escoger y poder guardar.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="form-group"> 
<label for=" codDist'">Distrito</label> 
<select class="form-control " id=" codDist'" placeholder="Enter username"></select> 
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    function cargaDistrito(depart, provin) {
        var $select = $('#codDist');
        $.ajax({data : {
                coddepartamento : depart,
                codprovincia : provin
                    },
                    url : "DistritPais",
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : 'JSON',
                    success : function(data) {
                        $select.html('');
                        $.each(data,
                        function(key, val) {
        $select.append('<option value="' + val.codDist + '">'+val.descrip+'</option>');})
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        $select.html('<option id="-1">Cargando...</option>');
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el html asociado a tu còdigo de jquery para poder ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Las funciones que llaman al departamento y la provincia se desarrollan correctamente, solo la función cargaDistrito carga por defecto el primer distrito, y necesito que no cargue esa opción sino “Seleccionar..” y el cliente pueda seleccionar antes de dar grabar.
El select lado cliente

Comment: Añade una opción vacía al select con texto SELECCIONE antes del $.each

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ayudo mucho, ya que apenas y estoy comenzando en el retador mundo de la programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de realizar el recorrido con each debes agregar un append ("  Seleccionar") y luego tu each para que te despliegue todos los datos que traes por ajax!

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta, me ayudo muchísimo.

Comment: De nada amigo , marca como favorita si es así y nos ayudamos !

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por su respuestas y quizás alguien lo necesite el código, corregido terminaría así:

```
function cargaDistrito(depart, provin) {
    var $select = $('#codDist');
    $.ajax({data : {
            coddepart : depart,
            codprovin : provin
                },
                url : "DistritPais",
                type : "GET",
                dataType : 'JSON',
                success : function(data) {
                    $select.html('');
```

$select.append('SELECCIONAR..

```
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $select.append('<option value="' + val.codDist + '">'+val.descrip+'</option>');})
                },
                error : function() {
                    $select.html('<option id="-1">Cargando...</option>');
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución más sencilla es utilizando append para añadir un valor al select antes de cargar los datos que provienen del JSON

```javascript
 $select.append(`<option value="-1">  SELECCIONE UNA OPCION </option>`);
```

En este artículo indica cómo añadir opciones a un select con JQuery [Cómo añadir enlaces con JQuery (ENG)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-options-to-a-select-element-using-jquery/)